# Indices of words that appear only once in a list

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

I have the following list of words:

```
x = ['Gaga', 'Gaga', 'Lam', 'Reem', 'Pal', 'Gaga','Lam']
```

I need to remove the words that appear only once, and return there indices, or positions.

```
y = ['Gaga', 'Gaga', 'Lam', 'Gaga', 'Lam']

loc = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Any simple function to do this?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 3):

Alternative *one-liner* with **`pandas`** module and its [`pd.Series.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) function:

```
In [80]: x = ['Gaga', 'Gaga', 'Lam', 'Reem', 'Pal', 'Gaga','Lam']

In [81]: (~pd.Series(x).duplicated(keep=False)).astype(int).tolist()
Out[81]: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

---

To remove all non-duplicates:

```
In [85]: s = pd.Series(x)

In [86]: s[s.duplicated(keep=False)].tolist()
Out[86]: ['Gaga', 'Gaga', 'Lam', 'Gaga', 'Lam']
```

Comment: Minor point, even better would be to calculate `s.duplicated(keep=False)` as an initial step and use it in both your calculations. But still +1 for a nice Panda solution.

Comment: @jpp, of course, when combining those 2 in one common block, `s = pd.Series(x)` and `dups = s.duplicated(keep=False)` should be calculated beforehand. I separated them for demonstration `pandas` one-liners

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` class for exactly this purpose:

```
from collections import Counter

x = ['Gaga', 'Gaga', 'Lam', 'Reem', 'Pal', 'Gaga','Lam']

c = Counter(x)

new_values = [item for item in x if c[item] > 1]
indexes = [1 if c[item] == 1 else 0 for item in x]

print(new_values)
print(indexes)
```

Output is:

```
['Gaga', 'Gaga', 'Lam', 'Gaga', 'Lam']
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: To note, O(n) as well. But not a big fan of the ternary vs `int(c['item'] == 1)`. Also, less efficient than mine since you test `c[item] == 1` in both list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and isolate items appearing only once. then use list comprehensions for your desired results. The solution is O(n) overall, although it involves 3 passes.

```
x = ['Gaga', 'Gaga', 'Lam', 'Reem', 'Pal', 'Gaga','Lam']

from collections import Counter

singles = {k for k, v in Counter(x).items() if v == 1}

y = [i for i in x if i not in singles]
loc = [int(i in singles) for i in x]

print(y, loc, sep='\n')

['Gaga', 'Gaga', 'Lam', 'Gaga', 'Lam']
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a new list, and work with that?

```
x = ['Gaga', 'Gaga', 'Lam', 'Reem', 'Pal', 'Gaga','Lam']
loc = []
new_x = []

for name in x:
    if x.count(name) == 1:
        loc.append(1)
    else:
        loc.append(0)
        new_x.append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension

```
x = ['Gaga', 'Gaga', 'Lam', 'Reem', 'Pal', 'Gaga', 'Lam'] 
y = [name for name in x if x.count(name) != 1]
```

## output

['Gaga', 'Gaga', 'Lam', 'Gaga', 'Lam']

Comment: this solution has a quadratic complexity in the number of elements of the list, which is not the best one